# I need to test this site in all the mobile device

Tags: android, iphone, blackberry, mobile

Is there any way to test my website in all mobile devices.

I have one link where we can test online - http://iphonetester.com/

Can anyone provide best solution to test Responsive design or websites in below online mobile devices.

- Android phone
- Blackberry
- iphone

Thanks in Advance

http://new.brandonplanning.com/home

I will be very thank full to them :)

Comment: Android and blackberry both have emulators that could be used to test your site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following for mobile testing (Please keep in mind that a real device is the best way to test)

- [Electric Plum iPhone Simulator](http://www.electricplum.com/dlsim.html) (there is a free version)
- [Opera Mobile Emulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/)

For Blackberry, you probably want to download RIM's Simulator / SDK. Android SDK is good for testing also.

Answer (score 1):

For the iPhone, you can download something called iPhoney.  It messes up sometimes, but it is probably the most accurate thing I have been able to find.

Answer (score -1):

utest.com provides testing services.

[UTEST](http://www.utest.com/)

They provide testing with all mobile devices however there is a cost to it